# How do you specify a string of goals as the defaultGoal in maven 2?

Tags: maven-2, build-process

I'm just curious, is there a way to specify that you want a string of goals run as the default goal in a maven project?  Is there an equivalent to Ant's `<project name="MyProject" basedir="." default="main"><target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something roughly equivalent, you CAN define a default goal or phase that will be executed if none is given in the `build` element:

```
<build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  ...
</build>
```

But this has to be a **single** phase, or goal, you can't pass multiple phases/goals (not really a problem since a phase triggers all preceding phases).

Here is what the POM Reference writes about `defaultGoal`:

> **`defaultGoal:`** the default goal or phase to execute if none is given. If a goal is given, it should be defined as it is in the command line (such as jar:jar). The same goes for if a phase is defined (such as install).

#### Reference

- POM Reference

  - 3.1.1 [The BaseBuild Element Set](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element)

Answer (score -3):

No there is no such thing in Maven to define a default goal neither a target (which does not exist in Maven), cause you will call maven allways with a goal e.g. mvn clean or mvn package etc.

Comment: Well, there is something and if you use it, you can call maven without a goal e.g. `mvn`.