# Maven questions

Tags: maven, default

When I just type mvn command in my machine where pom is located, which phase it is going to run? mvn install or deploy??

When I use mvn eclipse:eclipse in my machine to convert maven project to eclipse project, what phases it is going to execute from default life cycle? is it going to run all the phases again?

Answer (score 3):

> When I just type mvn command in my machine where pom is located, which phase it is going to run?

No goal is executed, instead you'll get:

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal [...]
```

You can specify default goal with the following `pom.xml` declaration:

```
<build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  ...
</build>
```

> When I use mvn eclipse:eclipse in my machine to convert maven project to eclipse project, what phases it is going to execute from default life cycle?

It's described in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html):

> #### Attributes:
>
> - Requires a Maven project to be executed.
> - Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `generate-resources` prior to executing itself.

## See also

- [How do you specify a string of goals as the defaultGoal in maven 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530306)